# How to select documentDB database azure using php?

Tags: php, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect with documentDB Azure using php but I didn't get it to work.  Now I am using the [code given here](https://github.com/cocteau666/AzureDocumentDB-PHP) but even that is not working. I can connect to the documentDB account but the problem is I can't select the database in my account. This is the selectDB function I am using

```
public function selectDB($db_name)
{
    $rid_db = false;
    $object = json_decode($this->listDatabases());
    $db_list = $object->Databases;
    foreach ($db_list as $value) 
    {
        if ($value->id === $db_name) 
        {
            $rid_db = $value->_rid;
        }
    }
    if (!$rid_db) 
    {
        $object = json_decode($this->createDatabase('{"id":"' . $db_name . '"}'));
        $rid_db = $object->_rid;
    }
    if ($rid_db) 
    {
        return new DocumentDBDatabase($this, $rid_db);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to debug it and find that listDatabases() function is not working (not selecting the databases in account) Here is the `listDatabase()` function:

```
public function listDatabases()
{
    $headers = $this->getAuthHeaders('GET', 'dbs', '');
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length:0';
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
    );
    return $this->request("/dbs", $options);
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Is the listDatabases request returning a 200? What's the response JSON look like? It should look like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt489065.aspx

Comment: When I am running this code on my local machine it is connecting to the database but when I am pushing this code to the local git repository on azure it's not working. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to your issue, you can add `var_dump(curl_error($curl));` in the `request` function in `phpdocumentdb.php` you required for troubleshooting the curl issues.

If you are developing on local or some dev environment, you may occur the SSL certificate issue. The curl error may output the message: **SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**.

And for developing, you can simple add sentence `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` in the `request` function in `phpdocumentdb.php` to bypass the SSL verification.

If you are in prod env, you should create SSL certificate in your PHP runtime. Refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/12/verify-peer-certificate-from-php-curl-for-azure-apps/ for more.

Comment: When I am running this code on my local machine it is connecting to the database but when I am pushing this code to the local git repository on azure it's not working. Do you know why?

Comment: by default, Azure PHP runtime do not have SSL certificate, you should create and config one, please refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/12/verify-peer-certificate-from-php-curl-for-azure-apps/.

Comment: Otherwise, you can simple add sentence curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); in the request function in phpdocumentdb.php to bypass the SSL verification. As I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hi Gary, curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); works for me.